# Is the domain for the google classroom account associated to a school or a district?

Tags: google-classroom

Is there a way to tell from the profile of a teacher and principal if they are in the same school or different schools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell it from the teachers` email addresses. If the part after the @ is different on each email address, then the teachers are in different schools (assuming both schools use custom email domains).